# Visual Studio 2019 git problem: "Cannot spawn ... ssh.exe: No such file or directory" on fetch/push

Tags: git, visual-studio, visual-studio-2019, openssh

Can't get VS2019 to fetch/push to the remote (happens to be on GitLab).  What is the correct configuration?

1. I'm using the built-in Windows 10 OpenSSH (`C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH`)
2. I've set env var `GIT_SSH=C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH\ssh.exe`
3. Private key loaded into running `ssh-agent` service via `ssh-add`.
4. From a normal command window (i.e., not a WSL bash shell) I can push/fetch to my heart's delight.
5. From VS2019, with the repo open (`Git>Local Repositories>myrepo`), when I try either `Git>Fetch` or `Git>Push` I get the following in the output window:

   ```
   Commit eebc0b4a created locally in repository r:\bbits\edu-bitcoin-staging
   Opening repositories:
   r:\bbits\edu-bitcoin-staging
   Pushing master
   Pushing to gitlab.com:bakins-bits/edu-bitcoin-staging.git
   Error: cannot spawn C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH\ssh.exe: No such file or directory
   Error encountered while pushing to the remote repository: Git failed with a fatal error.
   Git failed with a fatal error.
   unable to fork

   Failed to push to the remote repository. See the Output window for more details.
   ```

Note the `C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH\ssh.exe: No such file or directory` - and yet, that's the correct path:

```
C:\>dir C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH\ssh.exe
 Volume in drive C is P70-MSVC
 Volume Serial Number is 8240-9525

 Directory of C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH

10/15/2019  06:50 AM           882,688 ssh.exe
               1 File(s)        882,688 bytes
               0 Dir(s)  333,358,600,192 bytes free
```

Answer (score 7):

I think I've managed to resolve the issue here. Built-in Windows 10 `OpenSSH` is a 64-bit program. But the Git, that is running from within Visual Studio is 32-bit. Visual Studio uses the one in `C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TeamFoundation\Team Explorer\Git\mingw32\bin"` (adjust the path accordingly to your VS version).

The thing is, that Windows uses virtual folders to prevent 32-bit programs from accessing 64-bit libraries. So if 32-bit app tries to access `System32` folder, it is being redirected to `SysWOW64` instead. And there is no `OpenSSH` there. You can simulate that by trying to access `OpenSSH` folder from `32-bit` powershell window:

```
> cd C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH\
```

What you want to do is to set `GIT_SSH` to

```
C:\Windows\SysNative\OpenSSH\ssh.exe
```

SysNative is a virtual folder, it does not exist on your system physically. But by accessing it, program won't be redirected to `SysWOW64`

Comment: This resolved the issue that OP is asking about for me, but unfortunately it broke my command line implementation. Running git push in the Windows CLI after making this change gives me the following error -
`error: cannot spawn C:\Windows\SysNative\OpenSSH\ssh.exe: No such file or directory`

Comment: don't set the GIT_SSH as this will mess up other 64bit git. Open a cmd as admin, and run `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TeamFoundation\Team Explorer\Git\cmd\git.exe" config --system core.sshCommand  "C:/Windows/SysNative/OpenSSH/ssh.exe"`. This changes `{long vs2019 path}\etc\gitconfig` and will only affect the 32bit vs2019 bundled git.exe.

Answer (score 5):

Use this to escape space in "Program Files"

```
git config --global core.sshCommand 'C:\\PROGRA~1\\\\Git\\usr\\bin\\ssh.exe'
```

Answer (score 0):

Check first if the same push/pull from VS2019 would work with a VS2019 launched in a session where:

- `GIT_SSH` is *not* set
- `ssh.exe` is in `%PATH%` (meaning, before launching VS2019, a "`where ssh`" should return `C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH\ssh.exe` first, before `C:\path\to\Git\usr\bin\ssh.exe`)

I don't need to set `GIT_SSH` for those operations to work.

Comment: For this configuration do you leave "Credential helper" as "Unset", then?

Comment: @dav Credential helper? This is for HTTPS credential caching. As long as you are using SSH URLs, credential helper is not involved at all.